Why is the centrifugal force radially outwards?
The tendency of a body placed on a rotating frame (say with a uniform velocity) is to fly off tangential to the velocity of the plane.
Why then does the inertia of the body tend to take it radially outwards (which appears to be the centrifugal force for an observer on the plane)?
I am talking from an inertial frame, where I can invoke inertia of the body. Shouldn't the inertia be tangential?
My question is simply, how do I explain myself that the inertia (or the centrifugal force) has to be outward given that the tendency of the body is to fly off tangentially?

In the rotating reference frame (there is no need to mention observers) bodies do not fly off tangentially, but radially. This is because you need to subtract the rotational motion of the inertial frame.
Therefore, the "fictituous centrifugal forces" in the rotating reference frame are pointing outward.
Note, that in an inertial frame there is no fictituous force whatsoever. The reason bodies tend to fly off tangentially in the inertial frame is just Newtons first axiom, which applies as soon as you remove the centripetal force (e.g., you let loose of the rope).

But why don't the two observations reconcile practically? Or do they? Does the tangential fly off for an inertial observer look like a radially outwards fly off for an observer on the rotating frame?

The result of the observation is not the same, because the kind of observation is not the same. This can already seed when you compare different inertial frames. See here for an entertaining demonstration.

@Shubham If you convert the tangential straight line path in the inertial reference frame to the rotating reference frame then you get a curved path. Note that the path in the rotating reference frame is curved and not simply radially outwards because of Coriolis force - see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coriolis_force.

@gandalf61 is right. When I said that objects fly off radially, I only meant the initial direction of the curve. But for later times, you need to consider Coriolis force.

To be honest, the illustration on wikipedia is what confused me in the first place.
Imagine this, I am sitting on a turntable that contains friction and is not rotating yet, at some distance r from the axis. Just at the moment it begins to rotate, would I feel a jerk outwards, or tangentially backwards?
Please see the illustration on the below site, its again what has messed up my understanding:
https://www.jsme-fed.org/experiment-e/2012_4/005.html

If you watch a body in a circular motion from a non accelerated frame of view  outside the body, the body always has tendency to go tangentially to circle. But we all know that it doesn't go tangentially but it is in circular motion. Hence there must be a force which is changing the direction of body at every instant. This force is the centripetal force. Centripetal force always acts towards the centre, i.e. radially. Now, you must have observed , whenever you may have went past something that it doesn't seem that you have move past it rather it seems that the object is moving towards you. Observer always consider itself at rest. When you are in a train that is accelerating and you are looking outisde the window, you see the trees accelrating in a direction towards you. You will say, no net external force is acting on the trees but they are still moving. Hence to make Newton's Law applicable in this case you have to consider false force on trees in opposite direction of your acceleration. Now, If you observe from the accelerated frame of view of observer inside the body in Circular motion, then to ensure applicability of newton's laws of motion, just like the previous case you consider a false force in direction opposite to your direction of acceleration. Since your acceleration is towards centre due to centripetal force, you consider the false centrifugal force opposite the direction of centre. Thus it acts radially.
Thus for an observer in inertial frame, the body always has tendency to move tangentially and the acceleration of body is towards centre and as you go in the non inertial frame you consider acceleration radially outwards due to above stated reasons. And hence centrifugal force is radially outwards

I am aware of centrifugal force being a false or fictitious force invoked from the reference of the rotating plane. However here are a couple of key points:

When in the rotating plane you do not see yourself rotating, so you subtract the rotation. Now given this, centrifugal force arises because there is still a force pulling the body towards the center but unable to do so, hence a centrifugal force comes in to balance it, thereby keeping the net acceleration zero.
Centrifugal force, though fictitious, is as real in the rotating frame as any force, throwing things away from the center.


@Shubham Yes for the non inertial frame , centrifugal force though false is real.  So, what is your doubt then?

My doubt is, I can explain centrifugal force to be radially outwards when I am on the rotating frame. How do I explain that it must be radially outwards when I am in an inertial frame, when the inertia of the rotating body must be tangetial to the circular path. From an inertial frame, the inertia of the body must take it tangential and not radially outwards.

@Shubham See when you are in inertial frame the tendency of body is always to go tangentially. And acceleration is always towards centre.  There is no tendency to go radially outwards . So there is no need to explain yourself that "it must be radially outward when you are in inertial frame", since the inertia is not radially outwards and just tangential to the path.       I also doubt that you are thinking of inertia as a force, but inertia is simply tendency, it is not a force, it simply means if something is at rest or at uniform velocity it will just continue to be in that state.

@Shubham (This is extension of previous comment) , Any object will continue to be in its state of rest or uniform motion provided no external force is acting on it . Hope this clears your doubt

@Lukas Nullmeir's answer is correct, but not direct enough for my tastes:

In an inertial frame there is no centrifugal force, period, full stop, end-of-story. The centrifugal is a so-call fictitious force that appears in rotating frames.

In a frame rotating at $\vec \Omega$ (and $m=1$):


$$ F_c = -\vec \Omega \times (\vec \Omega \times r) $$
That expands to:
$$ \vec F_c = 
-\Big(\vec\Omega(\vec \Omega \cdot \vec r) - \Omega^2 \vec r \Big)$$
Now I can arbitrary define $\vec \Omega = \hat z$ to show
$$
\vec F_c = \vec r - \hat z (\hat z \cdot \vec r)
$$
where the right hand side is the vector rejection of $ \vec r$ onto $\vec z$ (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vector_projection), that is, it's the complement of the vector projection, and that, by definition: points straight outward from the $z$-axis, always.
An example of fictitious forces that I have never seen taught, but helps at least me understand how fictitious they are,  is a mass in an inertial frame at rest at
$$\vec r = r \hat x $$
$$ \vec v = 0$$
$$ \vec a = 0 $$
Pretty basic. Nothing is happening and there are no forces.
Now change coordinates to a rotating frame with
$$\vec \Omega = \Omega\hat z,$$
aligned at $t=0$:
So:
$$ \vec r' = r \hat x $$
$$ \vec v' = -\Omega r\hat y $$
$$ \vec a' = -\Omega^2 r\hat x $$
which is uniform circular motion. What forces keep it revolving around the origin?

There is an outward centrifugal force:

$$ \vec F_c = \Omega^2 r \hat x $$
which points the wrong way for the orbit. Let's check the Coriolis force:
$$ \vec F_C = -2\vec\Omega \times \vec v' $$
$$ \vec F_C = -2 \Omega(\Omega)r(\hat z \times -\hat y) $$
$$ \vec F_C = -2\Omega^2 r \hat x $$
Which, with the factor of 2 both overcomes the centrifugal force and keeps the mass orbiting in the rotating frames.
So to answer you question: does it always work out? A hard YES.
Physics DOES NOT CARE ABOUT YOUR COORDINATES! And:
$$ \vec F = m\vec a $$
is physics, so you need those fictitious forces to persevere Newton's laws. (Exercise: combine the previous statement with Special Relativity to derive General Relativity).
JK: a better exercise is the following:
Apply this to a mass orbiting a planet (or on a string) with $\vec \omega = n\vec \Omega$ with $n = (-2,-1,0,1,2)$ to convince yourself of that fact.
Regarding it flying off on a tangent. It does...or does it? [Vsauce face].
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AL2Chc6p_Kk

About the assertion: 'physics does not care about coordinates'. For sure that is true in the sense of notation of coordinates: whether cartesian coordinates or polar coordinates are used doesn't matter. The interesting case is inertial coordinate system versus non-inertial coordinate system. Take the case of a rotating coordinate system. Then the equation of motion contains the rotation rate of the rotating coordinate system with respect to the inertial coordinate system. That is: when a rotating coordinate system is used the underlying reference is still the inertial coordinate system.

Let $\Omega$ be the rotation rate of the rotating coordinate system with respect to the inertial coordinate system. The centrifugal term in the equation of motion is proportional to $\Omega^2$. The only way to use a rotating coordinate system at all is to retain the inertial coordinate system as the underlying reference. This extends to General Relativity in the following specific sense: the 43 arcseconds per century precession of the orbit of Mercury - accounted for by GR - is an (additional) precession relative to the inertial coordinate system.

well I think the 43 arc seconds is defined relative to the stress-energy tensor of the universe, which is part of system. You don't need to choose that coordinate system, it just makes the math easier. Without starting an epic tome on Newton's Bucket: we still have the small problem of vortex lines from Sag A*, which are forcing us to rotate relative to the distant stars in order to keep the bucket flat. We'll see in 115 million years when we on the other side of the galaxy.
